# Show that $|e^{\dot{\imath}x\cdot y}-1|\leq c|y|$, for $|y|<1$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

In the book "Robert Strichartz, Guide to distribution theory" last line of page 165 in the context of proving that
$$I(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{|e^{\dot{\imath}x\cdot y}-1|}{|y|^{n+2s}}dy=c|x|^{2s}$$

it says **near $y=0$** **use that
$|e^{\dot{\imath}x\cdot y}-1|\leq c|y|$ by the mean value theorem**

There is no condition or restriction on $x$ mentioned in this case.

So, I tried both the one-dimensional mean-value theorem and the $n$-dimensional mean value theorem. I always get

$$|e^{\dot{\imath}x\cdot y}-1|\leq c|y||x|$$

Here are the details:

Apply $1$-dimensional the mean value theorem to the smooth function $f(t)= e^{\dot{\imath}t}$ on $[0,x\cdot y]$ if $x\cdot y>0$ 0r the integral $[x\cdot y,0]$
of $x\cdot y<0$. We get
$$|f(t)-f(0)|=|e^{\dot{\imath}x\cdot y}-1|=|t|=|x\cdot y|\leq |x||y|.$$

Now, apply the $n$-dimensional the mean value theorem to the smooth function $f(y)= e^{\dot{\imath}y\cdot x}$ on the line segment $\lambda y+(1-\lambda)0$, $\lambda\in [0,1]$. We have $\nabla_{y}f(y)=\dot{\imath} x e^{\dot{\imath}y\cdot x}.$
So
$$|e^{\dot{\imath}y\cdot x}-1|=\lambda |y||x|.\qquad (1)$$

If one regards $ e^{\dot{\imath}y\cdot x} $  as a function of $x$ in stead, and use $n$-dimensional the mean value theorem on the line segment $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)0$ we also get (1) by symmetry.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps, the authors arguement is for a fixed $x$ in which case $C$ can depend on $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Changing variables $|x|y\rightarrow y$
$$I(x):=|x|^{2s}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{|e^{\dot{\imath}\frac{x}{|x|}\cdot y}-1|}{|y|^{n+2s}}dy=|x|^{2s}
\int_{|y|<1}\frac{|e^{\dot{\imath}\frac{x}{|x|}\cdot y}-1|}{|y|^{n+2s}}dy+
|x|^{2s}\int_{|y|\geq 1}\frac{|e^{\dot{\imath}\frac{x}{|x|}\cdot y}-1|}{|y|^{n+2s}}dy.$$

Then, applying the main value-theorem to $|e^{\dot{\imath}\frac{x}{|x|}\cdot y}-1|$
in the first integral gives $|e^{\dot{\imath}\frac{x}{|x|}\cdot y}-1|\leq |\frac{x}{|x|}||y|=|y|$ as explained in the question. The statement in the book is true for $|x|<1$ (there should have been some kind of hint...).

Answer (score 2):

Without restriction on $x$ the inequality is false. Take $n=1$ , $x=k$ and $y=\frac  1 k$ where $k$ is  a positive integer. The inequality becomes $|e^{i}-1|\leq \frac C k$. This canot hold for all $k$ whatever $C$ is.